# Is parallels 7 better in performance then Vmware Fusion 4?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, parallels-desktop, windows

I got Vmware Fusion 4 when I bought my MAC Book Pro ( core i7 2.0Ghz Quad Core 6MB Cache, 4GB RAM and 500GB HDD). I installed Win7 first on Vmware and then later WinXp. In both case the Virtual Machine was slow, it lagged and even the host OS LION, started to lag.

I assigned 1.5GB to 700++MB RAM and also gave upto 4 cores, but performance was slow.
Did some research online and found that Parallels 7 is alternate to vmware. But is parallels 7 better in performance compared to vmware fusion 4?

Comment: You might also want to consider VirtualBox, which is free and currently almost up to the features of Parallels and VMWare. It is a little bit less polished though (e.g. the 'guest additions' which give e.g. better mouse integration don't install automatically). [I was a previous Parallels user, up to version 4, but have since switched to VirtualBox]

Comment: This is a loaded question, and mileage will vary depending on the user and use case. In most review Parallels outperform VMWare 4, but those are still opinions and not facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ars Technica recently did a rundown of the performance differences between Parallels 7 and VMware Fusion 4: http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/10/virtual-showdown-parallels-desktop-7-and-vmware-fusion-4-reviewed.ars

The general takeaway seemed to me to be that Parallels is delivering better performance outside some very particular uses.